# Prove the limit by definition

Tags: limits

Prove the limit as x approaches 0 of (x+1) to the fourth power = 1.

I need help proving using the definition.

Comment: By visiting [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you can learn how to type mathematical expressions such as $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}(x+1)^4=1$ in MathJax and $\LaTeX$ instead of having to write out the expression in full English.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left|#1\right|}$Given $\epsilon > 0$, can you find $\delta > 0$ such that $\abs{x} < \delta \implies (x+1)^4 - 1 < \epsilon$?

Hint: Expand $(x + 1)^4 - 1= x^4 + 4x^3 + 6x^2 + 4x$. Observe that if $\delta < 1$, then $x^4,4x^3,6x^2,4x < 6x$.

Answer (score 0):

$lim_{x->0}(x+1)^4=1$

we accepet it and try to find $\epsilon$ In terms of $\delta$

so we have For All $\epsilon$ $\gt$ 0 (defenition) $\exists$  $\delta$ $\gt$0 
|x-0| $\le$ $\delta$ ==> |$(x+1)^4$-1|$\le$$\epsilon$

|x| $\le$ $\delta$
|$x^4+4x^3+6x^2+4x$|$\le$$\epsilon$

> and we know from Triangle inequality : $| x + y |\leq | {x}
>  |+|\mathbf {y} |$

|$x^4+4x^3+6x^2+4x$|$\le$$\epsilon$ ======> $|x^4+4x|+|6x^2+4x^3|$$\le$$\epsilon$

$|x||x^3+4|+|x^2||6+4x|$ (use |x|$\le$$\delta$ ) $\delta$|$x^3$+4|+$\delta^2$|6+4x|

now we can say ($\delta$ defenition) |x|$\le$$\delta$<1

so we have

|x|<$\delta$ ====> -$\delta$$\lt$x$\lt$$\delta$ ====> $(-\delta)^3$+4$\lt$$x^3$$+4\lt$$\delta^3$+4 =>|$x^3$-4|$\lt$$\delta^3$+4

|x|<$\delta$ ====> -$\delta$$\lt$x$\lt$$\delta$  ====> 4($-\delta$)+6 $\lt$4x$+6\lt$ 4$\delta$+6 => |4x+6|$\lt$4$\delta$+6

> $\delta$$\lt$1

10$\delta^2$+5$\delta$-$\epsilon$=0

we solve this equetion and we find a $\delta$ now if we select this delta:

> $\delta=min[\frac{-5 + \sqrt{5^2+40\epsilon}}{20}$,1]

now we can say that lim is corect for all $\epsilon$ $\gt$0